# How to specify more than one coordinates for geocode parameter of API.search in Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy, geocode, twitterapi-python

I want to search tweets based on more than one coordinates. So, I tried this but it doesn't return any results:

```
total = 0
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='cricket', lang="en",
                            geocode="24.8607,67.0011,25mi OR 40.7128,74.0060,20mi"
                           ).items(10):
    total+=1

print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since @Tayyap Mazhar shared the post, but just in case, the code below will work as expected. Just remember, do not put comma while declaring *geoc* variable!

````
import tweepy
import pandas as pd

CONSUMER_KEY = "?"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "?"
OAUTH_TOKEN = "?"
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = "?"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
auth.secure = True
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

if (not api):
    print ("Can’t Authenticate")
    sys.exit(-1)

tweet_lst=[]
geoc=[('41.0,28.9499962,1km'),('41.1062629083,29.0264182277,1km'),('41.072833042,29.022833242,1km'),('41.05,28.91,1km')]


for geocode in geoc:
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,geocode=geocode).items(1000):
        tweetDate = tweet.created_at.date()
        if(tweet.coordinates !=None):
            tweet_lst.append([tweetDate,tweet.id,tweet.
            coordinates['coordinates'][0],
            tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][1],
            tweet.user.screen_name,
            tweet.user.name, tweet.text,
            tweet.user._json['geo_enabled']])
            tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(tweet_lst, columns=['tweet_dt', 'id', 'long','lat','username', 'name', 'tweet','geo'])```
````